# The CW-structure for $J(S^n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Let $J(S^n)$ be the James unreduced product of $S^n$. In Hatcher, in the proof of proposition 3.22, it is claimed that $J(S^n)$ has a single cell in each dimension a multiple of n.

I am unable to see how to prove this, or even just on an intuitive level. Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Write the $mn$-cell in $(S^n)^m$ as $\underbrace{I^n\times\dots\times I^n}_m$ and we have the boundary $\bigcup_{k=1}^m ((I^n)^{k-1}\times(\partial I^n)\times (I^n)^{m-k})$ that we glue to $(S^n)^{m-1}$, because each $I^n$ collapse down to $S^n$ and $\partial I^n$ is the basepoint $0$-cell $e$.  All other $kn$-cells ($k<m$) of $(S^n)^m$ are part of the boundary so already in $(S^n)^{m-1}$.